# How can I get lodash type info to work in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am getting a (squiggly red line) error in VSCode with the following `.ts` file:

**src\lib\hi.ts**

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

function testLodash(): void {

  function square(n: number) {
    return n * n;
  }

  return _.map([4, 8], square);
}
```

**Error**

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'typeof import("lodash")'.ts(2339)
```

I get the same error for any of the usual lodash functions. Intellisense only gives me the `Lodash` class when invoked via `_.`.
I am guessing that VSCode can't find my type definitions but I can't see why.

If I change the import to:

```
import 'lodash';
```

I get the expected functions and the error goes away but i get a new error:

```
'_' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.ts(2686)
```

Applying the suggested QuickFix adds the following to imports:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

But then I get the original error back.

So what do I need to change to make this work?

Here are the details:

**package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.130",
    ...
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    "outDir": "./dist/",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "esModuleInterop": true                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
  }
}
```

**VSCode Settings**

No non-default TS settings

**TS Version**

Version 3.4.5

**VSCode Version**

```
Version: 1.34.0 (user setup)
Commit: a622c65b2c713c890fcf4fbf07cf34049d5fe758
Date: 2019-05-15T21:59:37.030Z
Electron: 3.1.8
Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
Node.js: 10.2.0
V8: 6.6.346.32
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17134
```

**Installed Extensions**

```
alanz.vscode-hie-server
alefragnani.Bookmarks
andyyaldoo.vscode-json
christian-kohler.path-intellisense
daiyy.quick-html-previewer
eamodio.gitlens
Edka.haskutil
esbenp.prettier-vscode
fabiospampinato.vscode-todo-plus
flowtype.flow-for-vscode
gcazaciuc.vscode-flow-ide
hoovercj.haskell-linter
jcanero.hoogle-vscode
justusadam.language-haskell
karigari.chat
mrmlnc.vscode-duplicate
ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin
ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare
ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare-audio
ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare-pack
phoityne.phoityne-vscode
SirTobi.code-clip-ring
WakaTime.vscode-wakatime
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have same issue, and I get through it by this way:

`const _ = require('lodash');`

Comment: I got another type error when I tried your solution : ```const _ : _.LoDashStatic = require('lodash');``` fixed that. It seems like a bit of a cludge but it works.

Comment: Why you need `_.LoDashStatic` type declaration?

Comment: without the type I got the following error: ```Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '_' must be of type 'LoDashStatic', but here has type 'any'.```

Comment: Can you try this https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/lodash#different-ways-people-might-use-lodash

Comment: I have rechecked, since my tsconfig has changed `target` to `es2015`
I can import like this: `import * as _ from 'lodash';`

Comment: I still get the same issue with `target` set to `es2015`. The only solution working for me is still: `const _ : _.LoDashStatic = require('lodash');`